# How create logger with logic in logback?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

Consider a code:

```
logger.into("MyMessage={}", myObject)
```

For some object type I need different representation, for example if this object is byte array I need to convert it as into integers and hex string and log them into 2 different files.
For now I have to use 2 loggers. Is there a way to detect object type at logging time and perform log separation and conversion automatically? E.g. every time when log back detects byte array into convert and
store into different places. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a wrapper class for the `Logger` class, and have the logic you described implemented in there.